# Lined up elements are a few pixels off

Tags: html, css, alignment

Alright, so I have an `input` box and a `submit` `button`. These are supposed to be lined up, and when the `button` doesn't have styling, they are. However, when I add style (like change the height and such), they become like `2px` off (by this I mean the space of the top of the `button` is like `2px` lower than the top of the `input` box). [Check it out here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0BdJ.png) As you can see in the photo, it is like the tiniest part off. However, if I try things that I know to line them up (like `display` and `line-height`), it doesn't do anything/the text in the `button` changes it's location too.

Any ideas? Here's the code:

```css
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(-42deg, #31E7F2 0%, #4ED57B 100%);
    font: 12px arial;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 35px;
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
}
  
form, p, span {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
}
  
input[type = "text"] { 
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 35px;
    display: inline-block;
}
input[type = "submit"] {
    background: #42EF73;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border: none;
    width: 70px;
}
input[type = "submit"]:focus {
    outline: none;
}
a {
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #0000FF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
  
a:hover { 
    text-decoration:underline;
}
  
#wrapper, #loginform {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    background: #EBF4FB;
    width: 504px;
    border: 1px solid #ACD8F0;
}
  
#loginform {
    padding-top: 18px;
}
  
#loginform p {
    margin: 5px;
}
  
#chatbox {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    height: 270px;
    width: 430px;
    border: 1px solid #ACD8F0;
    overflow: auto;
}
  
#logInButton {
    color: cyan;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#usermsg {
    width: 395px;
    border: 1px solid #ACD8F0;
}
  
#submit {
    width: 60px;
}
  
.error {
    color: #ff0000;
}
  
#menu {
    padding: 12.5px 25px 12.5px 25px;
}
  
.welcome {
    float: left;
}
  
.logout {
    float: right;
}
  
.msgln {
    margin: 0 0 2px 0;
}
#leaveMessage {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>CyanCoding Chat</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli" rel="stylesheet">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="menu">
                <p class="welcome">Welcome back!</p>
                <p class="logout"><a id="exit" href="#">Exit Chat</a></p>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
            </div>    
            <div id="chatbox"></div>
             
            <form name="message" action="">
                <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg"/>
                <input name="submitmsg" type="submit"  id="submitmsg" value="Send" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not really the fix you are looking for (I'm not really sure what is causing the issue) but the following changes even it up in my browser when I run your snippet:

```
/* Your code */
input[type = "text"] { 
    /*Your code*/
    box-sizing: border-box; // Add this line
}

input[type = "submit"] {
    /*Your code*/
    line-height: 37px; // Edit this line
}
```

Comment: When I do this, it does line up well, however, then the text isn't vertically aligned in the middle (and when I add that attribute, it messes it up again). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have various specific heights and line-heights for your elements, that is what is causing the alignment mismatch. For example, try add a `font-size` for that submit button, and you'll see that the height now changes, as does the alignment.

Try removing superfluous rules and then use flexbox to align the two elements.